# Explain Lookup+find function excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a combination of function like this

```
Formula of Cell B3
=LOOKUP(100,Find($E$2:$E$4,A3),$F$2:$F$4)
```

Purpose:

If cell `Ax` contains character of `Ex`, `Bx` will return the value of `Fx` (`x` is the number of row)

In this case the `Find($E$2:$E$4,A3)` always return `#Value` and I cannot understand why the above combination can return the right value.

Please refer to the picture below:

[image: Worksheet picture here]

Comment: Put code into snippets. More easier to read and understand the question

Comment: I don't understand what you are expecting `Find($E$2:$E$4,A3)` to do. What are you trying to search for in A3?

Comment: Is your goal to `SUM` all the values if a character is found in `Ax`? > e.g.: `axe` will return `1110`.? Or are you only interested in the first found value, in this case `a` and return `1000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find($E$2:$E$4,A3)` will return a three element array containing either the position each search item is found at, or a `#VALUE` error if it isn't present. The `LOOKUP` then looks for the number 100 in that array (the assumption being that the text being checked will never be longer than 100 characters), ignoring any error values. Since 100 should be larger than any number in the array, it will select the *last* number found (`LOOKUP` assumes the array is sorted in ascending order, and will return the last number less than or equal to the search value). The corresponding result from column F is then returned.

Comment: Good explanation except that when using `LOOKUP` in this manner (looking for a value greater than anything in the array), the array does not need to be sorted. For example, `=LOOKUP(9999,{"Z","x",1000,4,3})` --> `3`, and `=LOOKUP("zz",{"Z","x",1000,4,3})` --> `x`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I didn't say it *needs* to be sorted, just that LOOKUP *expects* it to be sorted. :)

Comment: if Find($E$2:$E$4,A3) stands alone, it returns #value, can you explain me what array the formula will return?

Comment: @Rory Sorry for my misunderstanding of what you wrote.  But the HELP files can be misleading in that regard, so I thought the emphasis worthwhile.

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan In the case of your formula in A3, it returns the array: `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;2}`.  Since you have entered it normally in a single cell, you will only see the first element of the array.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No worries - reading it back, I could have been a lot clearer about that I think!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you, I can see it by using Evaluate formula.